# Every state may be reached in time at most $N-1$ in a finite state space

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be an irreducible Markov chain, with finite state space 
>   $\mathbb{X}$ (of cardinality $N$). Prove that for $x_0\in \mathbb{X}$ the time $T_x=\inf\{k\geq 0:~X_k=x\}$ needed to reach a state $x\in \mathbb{X}$ is $\leq N-1$ (with positive probability).

*Attempt.* Since the chain is irreducible, for some (smallest) $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $p^{(n)}(x_0,x)>0$ and we have to show that $n\leq N-1$
(which would imply $T_x\leq N-1$). If $n\geq N$, then i don't seem to be able to get a contradiction.

Thank you!

Comment: Should it be $<N-1$ or $\le N-1$? I think it is the latter as you could have your transition matrix be the cyclic shift operator.

Comment: That's...just not true as stated. It is true that $P(T_x \leq N-1)>0$, but it is just not true that it is $1$ in general. For example it could be that $p(x_0,x_0)>0$ in which case it is possible for the chain to just sit at $x_0$ for $N$ steps or even more. Edit: OP was corrected :)

Comment: @Ian 60% of the time, it works every time.

Comment: Just edited thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the definition of irreducibility, you are implicitly given a path $P_k$ with $P_0=x_0,P_m=x$ which has positive probability, but where perhaps $m>N-1$. Suppose it is. Then the path has more than $N$ points in it, so some point is repeated (this is just the pigeonhole principle). This cycle can be pruned out from $P_k$ to create a new, shorter path from $x_0$ to $x$ which also has positive probability.  Can you use this pruning procedure to finish the argument?

Comment: For OP: This is basically a pigeonhole problem, cleverly disguised in Markov chain terminology.

Comment: @CameronWilliams There is a tiny bit more to it, since a single pruning does not necessarily do the job. But yes, the pigeonhole observation is the key.

Comment: Right, right! :)

Comment: Let $x_0, ..., x_m$ be a path (of positive  probability) where $ x_0,...,x_m$ are distinct. What kind of argument (is it here that pigeonhole principle is used?) gives us the next state in a way that $ x$ is reached within $N  -1$ steps?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout If the points are all distinct then $m \leq N-1$ by the pigeonhole principle (because each $x_i$ is in the state space which only has $N$ elements to begin with). The argument I suggested does not assume that the path that we are given from the start consists of distinct elements, though this kind of argumentation can be used to show that such a path does in fact exist (and have positive probability of course).

Answer (score 1):

Following the hints given above by @Ian, for sake of completeness, I ll post a detailed answer: since $x_0,~x$ communicate, there is a path $x_0 \rightarrow x_1 \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow x_m=x$ of positive probability that starts from $x_0$ and leads to $x_m=x$.

*Claim*: there is a subpath $x_0=x_{k_0} \rightarrow x_{k_1} \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow x_{k_\ell}=x$ such that $k_0=0 <k_1<\ldots<k_\ell\leq N-1$ (therefore $\ell\leq N-1$), such that states $x_{k_0},x_{k_1},\ldots,x_{k_\ell}$ are all distinct. Then, with positive probability, $T_x=\ell\leq N-1.$

*Proof of claim*: Let  $k_0=0 <k_1<\ldots<k_r$ be as desired. If 
$x_{k_r}=x$ then we are done, otherwise pic $k_{r+1}$ such that $x_{k_{r+1}}$ is the next state of the given path, distinct from $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{k_r}$. The procedure is finished in at most $N-1$ steps.

[image]

*Image*: (an example) the path of 13 states may be reduced to a path of 8 states, leading with positive probability to $x$.